# Posting a single page HTML as app on facebook

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I have a single page HTML which contains few quizzes that user can play. The page contains the javascript required to play the quiz. I have posted the HTML in AWS so that I have a page URL for the HTML. All I am trying to do is to post this HTML as an app on facebook using my developer account. But whatever I try, I get an error page when I try to access the app URL using the app id.

Is it possible to post an HTML page as an app on facebook? If so is there any relevant documentation. I have been around this for a couple of days now. I found few docs, but they are very old and the Facebook UI has changed. So it is not working for me. Any help would be highly appreciated.

I try to access the app using the URL:

[https://apps.facebook.com/{app_id}](https://apps.facebook.com/831064597077117), [image: Error Message]

But I am not trying to post it as a game, its just simple quiz for kids.

Comment: _"But I am not trying to post it as a game"_ - well what then? The address you tried to access it under is for the Web Games Platform, so if you are not using that, then ... Page Tab platform maybe? The documentation for that has explicit instructions on how to install the app on a page.

Comment: @CBroe, I just want my HTML page to be posted as an app on Facebook and the category that I have selected is quizzes and horescope

Comment: You can either embed your external content as a Page Tab, or via the Web Games platform.

Comment: @CBroe, where can I find some instructions for that, I was stuck after following the instructions from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/register.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/gamesonfacebook/hosting